# Is there HTML/PHP code to make a LibreOffice Export?

Tags: php, html, css, export, libreoffice

Right, so...

**The situation:**

*I'm working on a website to make prints of customer orders, and this will eventually run **LOCALLY** on a Linux Mint 19 machine. The problem I'm currently facing is using the website to export the filled in fields to a libreoffice document or a print.*

**The problem:**

*I haven't fully finished the website yet, I've been experimenting with a few simple textboxes on a blank page with tags like: "Name" and "Location". I'm currently still unsuccesfull.*

**THINGS I TRIED TO USE:**

- PHPword

If you guys can tell me a universal solution to make a website with textboxes to fill and export this to a LibreOffice document that's easy to apply, I'd be thankfull!

Comment: What didn't work when you tried to use PHP WordPress? It's likely someone will still suggest using it, since it's basically what you're looking for.

Comment: Well I was making a website using Visual Studio Code, since I program my websites using XAMPP to locally run them. The problem here is that when I hit the export button which should trigger the export does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PhpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) can be used. This works with Microsoft Office and LibreOffice (5.4.1.2 confirmed). But it isn't maintained anymore. Have a lookt at [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) (not tested).